# How to sort a list of generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics, sorting

I have a set of classes that all share some common attributes, so I made them all extend a common base class, `BaseEntity`.  So I have, for example `Foo extends BaseEntity` and `Bar extends BaseEntity`.

I also want lists of these `Foo` and `Bar` objects to be sortable, so I have implemented `Comparable`.  I have the classes defined as `Foo extends BaseEntity implements Comparable<Foo>` and `Bar extends BaseEntity implements Comparable<Bar>`, and sorting of lists of `Foo`s or `Bar`s works as expected - and, of course, the details of the sorting are different in the different subclasses.  But I can't work out how to make my sorting work when I don't know in advance whether I'll have `Foo`s or `Bar`s.  This code, for example,  fails to compile:

```
public class UtilityClass<T extends BaseEntity> {

  ...bunch of stuff...

  List<T> values;

  public List<T> sort() {
    Collections.sort(values);
    return values;
  }

  ...more methods...
}
```

with the error message `Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<T>). The inferred type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

I think the problem is that I am attempting to sort a list of `BaseEntity` objects, and `BaseEntity` itself doesn't implement `Comparable`.  But now I face a problem: the only sensible thing to make `BaseEntity` objects comparable to is other `BaseEntity` objects, but when I add `implements Comparable<BaseEntity>` to `BaseEntity`, the compiler tells me that I've got problems now because my `Foo` class is trying to implement both `Comparable<BaseEntity>` and `Comparable<Foo>`, which evidently is not allowed.

I know I could sidestep this issue by dropping the `implements Comparable<Foo>` and just implementing `Comparable<BaseEntity>`, but then my `compareTo` methods will have to do ugly casting, and I thought that was exactly the sort of problem using generics was supposed to avoid.

What I really want to do is specify in the signature of `BaseEntity` that all its subclasses will be `Comparable`, but only to instances of the same subclass.

Any assistance gratefully received.  Thanks!

Comment: I am sure you want to sort a list of objects, not types?

Comment: So you will have either a list of `Bar` or a list of `Foo` but not both in the same one? Is your `MyList` template going to be more involved? If not it seems like an unnecessary layer which is causing your issue.

Comment: Yes, my list is either `Foo` or `Bar`, and yes, the `MyList` is just a sample of the smallest possible code that shows the problem I'm having.  The real class is a lot more complex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an intersection type, like this:

```
public class MyList<T extends BaseEntity & Comparable<T>> {...}
```

That specifies that T must be both a `BaseEntity` **and** `Comparable` to itself.

Comment: The `MyList` class was just an example to show the error message.  I chose a bad name :-(, this isn't actually a list of anything and instances of this class just need to perform the sorting, not actually be sortable themselves.

Comment: I don't see why that would change the applicability of the answer, though. :)

Comment: because generics in java 5 is lame. the error 'like trying to implement both `Comparable<BaseEntity>` and `Comparable<Foo>`, which evidently is not allowed' obviously suggested it.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right.  That `Comparable<T>` applies to `T`, not to `MyList`.  Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: for best results, use `<T extends BaseEntity & Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: @newacct cn u explain what <T extends BaseEntity & Comparable<? super T>> actually does?

Comment: @TusharBanne: `Comparable` is a consumer and so should always be used with `? super` wildcards, according to the PECS rule. Without the `? super` wildcard, if you have a class that is comparable to itself, its subclass cannot be used as `T` here, even though it should be able to.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Collections.sort(List<T>)`, use `Collections.sort(Lst<T>, Comparator<? extends T>)` instead. Write the comparation code in the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> sort(T[] array);
```

This is the most general specification to accomplish the task. Basically, it asserts, that T is a type which can be compared to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a super-simple sort method that can handle pretty much any List type

```
public class Tools {

    public static <E> void sortList(List<E> list, Comparator<E> comparator) {
        Collections.sort(list, comparator); 
    }

    // Any other utility methods/resources you want in here

}
```

This means you can call this method to sort any List so long as the given List and Comparator are of the same Type as each other. It would work even without the base class you have (BaseEntity)