# How to sort list of array type in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

As my question describes, how to sort the list of type array in java?

This is my ListClass

```
package AlgorithmAndDataStructures;
public class ListClass<T>{
    private static final int MAX_SIZE_OF_LIST = 100;
    /**
     * This class is having definitions for:-
     * Generic List Class Variables
     * Constructor for Creating Class Objects
     * Method: Adding a Element to the End of List
     * Method: Adding a Element at anywhere/ particular place
     * Method: Checking List is full or not.
     * Method: Checking List is Empty or Not.
     * Method: Displaying All Elements of List
     * Method: Making New Space for new element addition.
     * Method: Sorting a List
     */

    // Declaring Array and Variables
    private T[] listArray;
    private int totalElements;

    // Constructor For ListClass
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ListClass(int listSize) { // entered by the user on runtime
        totalElements = 0;
        listArray = (T[]) new Object[listSize];
    }

    // Method For Adding an Element
    public boolean addElement(T newElement)
    {
        boolean isElementAdded = true;
        if(!isListFull()) {
            listArray[totalElements] = newElement;
            totalElements++;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry, the list is full so, new element can not      be added.");
            isElementAdded = false;
        return isElementAdded;
    }

    // length = totalElements
    // Method for Adding/Inserting Element in any Particular Place
    public boolean addSpecific(int newLocation, T newElement) {
        boolean elementAdded = true;
        if (!isListFull() && (newLocation >= 1) && (newLocation <= totalElements +1) )
        {
            newSpace(newLocation);
            listArray[newLocation -1] = newElement;
            totalElements++;
            }
        else {
            elementAdded = false;
        }
        return elementAdded;
    }

    // Method for Displaying The List Elements
        public void displayListElement() {
            if(isListEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, there is no element in the List!");
            }
            else 
            {
            for(int elements = 0; elements < totalElements; elements++  ) {
                System.out.println((listArray[elements]));
            }
            System.out.println("All elements has been displayed!");

            }
        }

    // Method for Checking if List is Empty or Number of elements = 0
    public boolean isListEmpty() {
        return totalElements == 0;
    }
    // Method for Checking is List is full or not. 
    public boolean isListFull() 
    {
        return totalElements == MAX_SIZE_OF_LIST;
    }

    private void newSpace( int newLocation)
    {
        // assert is a method predefined; indicator for index number
    assert (newLocation >=1) && (newLocation <= totalElements +1);
    int newIndicator = newLocation -1;
    int lastIndicator = totalElements -1;
    /**
     * For Shifting Elements to Next Indexes
     */
    for ( int sign = lastIndicator; sign >= newIndicator; sign--)
    listArray[sign +1] = listArray[sign];
    }


}
```

**And this is my DriverProgram**

```
package AlgorithmAndDataStructures;

public class DriverListClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ListClass<Integer> listObjectInt = new ListClass<Integer>(10);
        listObjectInt.addElement(12);
        listObjectInt.addElement(17);
        listObjectInt.addElement(90);
        listObjectInt.addElement(53);
        listObjectInt.addSpecific(3, 56);
        listObjectInt.displayListElement();


        // String List
        ListClass<String> listObjectStr = new ListClass<String>(4);
        listObjectStr.addElement("Suman");
        listObjectStr.addElement("Armaan");
        listObjectStr.addElement("Atif");
        listObjectStr.addElement("Tauseef");
        listObjectStr.displayListElement();
    }

}
```

Now, I want a generic sorting method in the **ListClass** that could sort the list of any type (String, Integer, Double, Float, etc) generated through driver program.

Comment: Most elements that are sortable implements `Comparable<T>`, you can cast things to that class and call `compareTo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort List of User-defined type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407784/how-to-sort-list-of-user-defined-type-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a list of generic types in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577910/how-to-sort-a-list-of-generic-types-in-java) ... please search SO before posting.

Comment: Alright, I have implemented Comparable<T> to the ListClass but how do I actually write compareTo method for my case. The link you give me is not understandable by me as it is for specific String Type.

Comment: Depending on the order of the objects a and b, the function should return -1 if a<b, 0 if a==b and 1 if a>b.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971918/sorting-an-arraylist-based-on-a-class-data-members-data-member/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add sort method to your class

```
public void sort() {
    Arrays.sort(listArray, 0, totalElements);
}
```

And change `class ListClass<T>` to `class ListClass<T extends Comparable<T>>`.

If you want to sort by specific Comparator, add method below.

```
public void sort(Comparator<T> comparator) {
    Arrays.sort(listArray, 0, totalElements, comparator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a comparison method for the elements of a list. This is usually done by making the elements implement an interface like `Comparable`:
`public class ListClass<T extends Comparble<T>>`

Comment: I have implemented it as an interface. But, I am unable to understand how to write compareTo method for generic type then.. Eclipse has already created this  `@Override
 public int compareTo(T o) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 0;` but how it'll sort the elements of any type?

Comment: You need to implement it for any type you want to sort. There is no natural sorting order for most types, even for strings, sort order strongly depends on the language.